# cannot make logo text (font-face) look similar to how firefox renders (issue is Internet Explorer)

Tags: css, cross-browser

I use Lobster font, and it looks completely different in two chrome/firefox/opera/safari vs internet explorer.

It doesn't work in IE8, 7

You can see example here: [dev.holiday.ge/xhtml](http://dev.holiday.ge/xhtml) -> look at the red logo in firefox vs IE.

Comment: IMHO, logos should always be a purely graphical element to guarantee 100% consistency in branding across all media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in:
dev.holiday.ge/xhtml/all-ie-only.css

you have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    src: url('fonts/DroidSans.eot');
}
```

this should be something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    src: url('fonts/Lobster.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Lobster.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
}
```

if you have the .eot

For best font compatibility use this syntax:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */   
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */

}
```

Comment: my god, can't believe I did this stupid mistake :) thx for help.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? Also, are you sure the @font-face rule in that file isn't overwritten by other @font-face rules in other css files? E.g. `style.css` also has @font-faces.

Comment: no worries you just needed a fresh set of eyes, i just updated my answer to include extra information. try passing the format for older i.e browsers.

Comment: :) thx, tried new update code too, but still fonts don't load in 7-8. damn this is becoming complicated.

Comment: alternatively you can consider loading it from google apis [link](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster) or by an import: @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);

Comment: I got it, my .eot files were not good. So ie9w as using wof, and the rest were failing. I regenerated font files and it fixed my issues. thx !! :)